# Why timer is getting stopped after tapping on the textfield in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I want to run timer in tableViewHeader part, the tableView header is containing textField ,label and button. To manage the timer I have created singleton class and it's working fine in the initial but when I tap on textField the timer getting stopped. I don't why. Should I manage it using separate thread?

//singleton class

```
class WorkoutTimerManager {
    static let shared = WorkoutTimerManager()
    private var sec = 0
    private var min = 0
    private var timer = Timer()
    private var date: Date? = Date()
    var timerLbl:UILabel?
    private init() {
        
    }
    
    func startTimer() {
       timer.invalidate()
       timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    func stopTimer() {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    
    
   @objc func updateTimer() {
      if let date = self.date {
          let elapsedSec = abs(Int(date.timeIntervalSinceNow))
          self.sec = elapsedSec % 60
          self.min = elapsedSec / 60
          print("sdfs1 \(sec)")
          if let timerLbl = timerLbl {
              timerLbl.text = "\(sec)"
              print("sdfs2 \(sec)")
          }
          
          
      }
   }
    
    
}
```

// table view headerview delegate method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        
        let name = "EmptyWorkoutHeader"
        guard
            let nib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(name, owner: nil, options: nil)
            else { fatalError("missing expected nib named: \(name)") }
        guard
            let headerView = nib.first as? EmptyWorkoutHeader
            else { fatalError("view of type \(name) not found in \(nib)") }
        
        WorkoutTimerManager.shared.timerLbl = headerView.timerLbl
        WorkoutTimerManager.shared.startTimer()
        
        
        return headerView
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It is a code smell to pass a UIView to your timer singleton. You are coupling unrelated objects. You should probably just create the timer in your header view. You should also run your timer at at least 0.5s to provide smoother updates and account for jitter.

Comment: Actually I need to run the timer in background as well and the timer values has to be passed to another view that's why I have created the singleton for it

Comment: when I would press on the top left button then this controller would be dismissed and a small window would be shown with the running timer

Comment: You only need to pass the model; that is the `Date` instance that the elapsed time starts from. Time continues to elapse because that is the way the universe works . You can have another `Timer` in another view to update that view.

Comment: but even after putting the code within header swift file it's getting stopped after tapping on the textfield

Comment: oh it was simulator issue working fine on iPhone, and thanks @Paulw11

Comment: You should NOT manage your timer from a separate thread. A timer running on a separate thread will call it’s selector on that thread, and you risk crashing if you then try to update the UI from that selector. There is no reason to mess with threads for timers.

Comment: Add your timer in runloop: `RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .common)`